# How to fire an event after a kendo comboBox has finished a filter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I need to fire an event after my combo box finishes its filter

I have extended the widget and have tried to chuck a .done on the end of the call.

```
    search: function(word) {
        word = typeof word === "string" ? word : this.text();
        var that = this,
            length = word.length,
            options = that.options,
            ignoreCase = options.ignoreCase,
            filter = options.filter,
            field = options.dataTextField;

        clearTimeout(that._typing);

        if (length >= options.minLength) {
            that._state = STATE_FILTER;
            if (filter === "none") {
                that._filter(word);
            } else {
                that._open = true;
                that._filterSource({
                    value: ignoreCase ? word.toLowerCase() : word,
                    field: field,
                    operator: filter,
                    ignoreCase: ignoreCase
                }); // .done here does not work :(
            }
        }
    },
```

I need to know when a value is returned so that I can do some other stuff on my page once i know that the input matches a value server side.

Can anybody think of a way to achieve this? :)

Is there a way to fire an event once the datasource has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the _busy state on the widget.
The following code is in the select function on the widget so whenever someone losses focus this fires.

If the widget is not busy it will have finished the ajax call.
Hope this is usefull to someone :)

```
    if (data && data.length != 0) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
            li = $(that.ul).find('li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
            if (li.length != 0 && data[i].ProductCode == that.input.val()) 
            {
                that._select(li);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if (that._busy && that._busy != null)
    {
        that.busyCheck = setInterval(function () {
            if (!that._busy || that._busy == null) {
                clearInterval(that.busyCheck);
                if (data && data.length != 0){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        li = $(that.ul).find('li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                        if (li.length != 0 && data[i].ProductCode == that.input.val()){
                            that._select(li);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 50);
    } 
    that._AddcodeIsServerValid(false);
```